# Is the following static method thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, static, thread-safety

I found the following method in our code base today, and it strikes me that it might not be thread-safe.  I think IEnumerable could be a reference type, and could potentially be modified by another thread while this code is executing.  Is that correct, or is this method thread-safe after all?  If not, is it appropriate for this method to be static?  It seems like making it an instance method wouldn't change the possibility of the entities parameter being modified in another thread.

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the Entity data in <paramref name="entities"/> to a CSV file located at <paramref name="path"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The Entity Type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="entities">A List of Type LinqEntityBase.</param>
/// <param name="path">The location of the CSV file.</param>
internal static void LinqEntitiesToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities, string path) where T : LinqEntityBase
{
    var entityBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> columnInfos = GetColumnInfos<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < columnInfos.Count; i++)
    {
        string columnName = columnInfos[i].Key;
        entityBuilder.Append(columnName.Contains(',') ? columnName.WrapIn('\"') : columnName);
        entityBuilder.Append(i < columnInfos.Count - 1 ? "," : string.Empty);
    }

    entityBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);

    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof (T).GetPropertiesFromCache().ToArray();
    foreach (T entity in entities)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < propertyInfos.Length; i++)
        {
            var columnAttribute = Attribute
                                        .GetCustomAttribute(propertyInfos[i], typeof (ColumnAttribute))
                                    as ColumnAttribute;
            if (columnAttribute == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            object value = propertyInfos[i].GetValue(entity, null);
            string valueString = (value != null) ? value.ToString() : string.Empty;

            entityBuilder.Append(valueString.Contains(',') ? valueString.WrapIn('\"') : valueString);
            entityBuilder.Append(i < columnInfos.Count - 1 ? "," : string.Empty);
        }

        entityBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    FileHelper.TryWriteTextFile(path, entityBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.

The actual safety of the method depends on what you kind of IEnumerable you pass it; thread safety rarely exists in a vacuum.
For example, all of the concurrent collections are *completely* thread-safe, even for concurrent writes and enumerations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That is pretty much what I thought.  What approach should I take to make it thread safe in pre .Net 4.0?  My immediate thought is to either put the whole thing inside a lock on the entities parameter or copy the IEnumerable into a list.  The 2nd option makes the assumption that I don't care if somebody modifies the underlying data structure after I copy it, though.

Comment: It completely depends on what you're passing to the method.

Comment: This method says that T must be or extend type LinqEntityBase.  LingEntityBase is a concrete class, so we're passing an IEnumberable of concrete classes to the method.  Is that enough info?

Comment: That doesn't make any difference at all.  It depends on the implementation of the _enumerable_.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it is perfectly possible that somewhere else the **underlying data structure** of the `IEnumerable entities` is being modified by a different thread while this method iterates over it.

Pay attention to **underlying data structure**. `IEnumerable` itself is not a concrete class, so it could be anything behind it.

Having said this, whether the method is static or not makes no difference, the only question is whether all threads share the `entities` collection.